# Is there a way to obfuscate a class name but not the members with R8

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I have a bunch of Retrofit Request/Response classes that get (de)serialized with GSON.

I currently use @Keep to make sure that R8 doesn't make them abstract, or obfuscate the property names (which are needed for GSON).

Is there any way I can obfuscate the class name while not obfuscating the property names, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `-keepclassmembernames`

**As per proguard manual [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#keepoptions)**

> `-keepclassmembernames class_specification`
>
> Short for-keepclassmembers,allowshrinkingclass_specification Specifies
>   class members whose names are to be preserved, if they aren't removed
>   in the shrinking phase. For example, you may want to preserve the name
>   of the synthetic class$methods when processing a library compiled by
>   JDK 1.2 or older, so obfuscators can detect it again when processing
>   an application that uses the processed library (although ProGuard
>   itself doesn't need this). Only applicable when obfuscating.